# How to get the data from an HTML page and store it into SQL Sever

Tags: .net, asp.net, html, sql-server

I have my a HTML page) where user will have to login first.

My question is how can i get the value of the TextBox from that HTML page to a ASP.NET page?

P.S. Will `Request.Form()` method will work??

Comment: If the textbox is an asp.net TextBox object then you would assign it an ID on the .aspx page, and reference it from the code behind in order to grab its .Text property.

Answer (score 0):

Request.Form[] will work as long as your html page has the inputs within a form that posts to a page on your asp.net application.

Answer (score 0):

Try to create a javascript function which gets the values of the textboxes in html form and pass them as query string for the page you are redirecting.

in javascript:

```
function Text(textbox) {
            var btn = document.getElementById('btnSubmit');
            var text = document.getElementById(textbox.id);
            btn.href = btn.href +'?'+ text.value;
        }
```

in html page:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
      Text:  <input id="txtBox" type="text" onchange="Text(this);" />
        <a id="btnSubmit" href="Default.aspx">Submit</a>
    </div>
 </form>
```

So, when you click Submit u'll find the link with query string like this :

```
http://localhost/Test/Default.aspx?test
```

Mark as answer if it helps!